# Full Size AmCharts

Tags: javascript, php, amcharts

I am using AmCharts for my website, I would like to make it full size. FOr example, I have this code:

```
<style>
#chartdiv {
width : 50%;
height : 500px;
float : left;
}
</style>
<script>
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
"type": "pie",
"theme": "light",
"autoMargins": false,
"marginTop": 2,
"marginBottom": 2,
"marginLeft": 2,
"marginRight": 2,
"fontSize": 14,
"dataProvider": [
{
"type": "Open Issues",
"number": op
},
{
"type": "Closed Issues",
"number": cl
},
{
"type": "Deferred Issues",
"number": df
},
{
"type": "Vendor Issues",
"number": ve
},
{
"type": "FAQ Issues",
"number": fq
}
],
"valueField": "number",
"titleField": "type",
"export": {
"enabled": true,
"libs": {
"path": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/libs/"
}
}
} );
</script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

I want to make the charts expand fully. Is that possible? I referred to their site help. It said to use margins as 0 and set automargins as false, I have tried that but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 width : 100%;
 height : 100%;
```

Make sure you don't have any parent div above chart div.

Comment: i want the chart alone to be bigger. not the full div bro.

Comment: it kind of makes the size bigger but i need to reduce the size of text as the text is also considered as a part of div